# Cannot import twython from Twython: ProtocolError and name certs error

Tags: python, ipython, twython

While using python, I'm having trouble importing twython. The installation seems to be fine, but for some reason I get the following errors below.  The first time I try to import I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolError" and every subsequent attempt results in the following error "ImportError: cannot import name certs".  There may be a simple solution to this, but I'm at a loss.

```html
In [1]: from twython import Twython
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d48648e29d1e> in <module>()
----> 1 from twython import Twython

/Users/Rush/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/twython/__init__.py in <module>()

/Users/Rush/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/twython/api.py in <module>()

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py in <module>()
     56     pass
     57 
---> 58 from . import utils
     59 from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
     60 from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py in <module>()
     23 from . import __version__
     24 from . import certs
---> 25 from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
     26 from .compat import (quote, urlparse, bytes, str, OrderedDict, unquote, is_py2,
     27                      builtin_str, getproxies, proxy_bypass)

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py in <module>()
      5 """
      6 
----> 7 from .packages import charade as chardet
      8 
      9 import sys

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import urllib3

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py in <module>()
     14 
     15 
---> 16 from .connectionpool import (
     17     HTTPConnectionPool,
     18     HTTPSConnectionPool,

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in <module>()
     31 from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError
     32 from .packages import six
---> 33 from .connection import (
     34     DummyConnection,
     35     HTTPConnection, HTTPSConnection, VerifiedHTTPSConnection,

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py in <module>()
     39 )
     40 from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname
---> 41 from .util import (
     42     assert_fingerprint,
     43     resolve_cert_reqs,

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 )
     17 
---> 18 from .retry import Retry
     19 from .url import (
     20     get_host,

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in <module>()
      2 import logging
      3 
----> 4 from ..exceptions import (
      5     ProtocolError,
      6     ConnectTimeoutError,

ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolError



#####################################################################################
#####################################################################################
#####################################################################################




In [2]: from twython import Twython
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d48648e29d1e> in <module>()
----> 1 from twython import Twython

/Users/Rush/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/twython/__init__.py in <module>()

/Users/Rush/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/twython/api.py in <module>()

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py in <module>()
     56     pass
     57 
---> 58 from . import utils
     59 from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
     60 from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options

/Users/Rush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 from . import __version__
---> 24 from . import certs
     25 from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
     26 from .compat import (quote, urlparse, bytes, str, OrderedDict, unquote, is_py2,

ImportError: cannot import name certs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a manifestation of this issue: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2028
I solved it by reinstalling requests:

`pip uninstall requests`

and then

`pip install requests`